# How does writing to CPU register actually work?

Tags: windows, assembly, cpu, intel

When writing to a register, say, like `mov ax, 1`, it overwrites the value it may have had earlier.

Now what I wonder is that how big figures/strings can I feed into a register, and that can another application overwrite my app's register values? I mean, are the registers shared among processes or do they receive their own sandboxed/virtual registers?

I am interesting in Intel x86(-64) Core CPUs and Windows.

Comment: Note: at this basic level the OS doesn't really matter: everyone does it the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thread is scheduled at a time on a single core. The core is what has the registers.

When a new thread is scheduled, the registers are first saved, and the previously-saved registers of the thread are restored. This includes the Program Counter register, which points to the next instruction to execute.

---

Registers (from memory):

AX, BX, CX, DX are 16 bits, broken into bytes (AH, AL, BH, BL)
SI, DI, SP and BP are also 16 bits

EAX, EBX, ECX etc. are 32 bits

I'm not sure what they're called on a 64-bit system. I think I saw RAX, but I'm not sure.

There are also special-purpose registers, floating-point registers, etc.

Comment: That cleared up a lot. Do you happen to know the limitations applied to registers -- i.e., how much data and what types. I'd be happy to take links since I can't really find Intel documentation on this...

Comment: How can you not find documentation?

Comment: registers are bits, that is all, ones and zeros.  They have no meaning until you do something with them.  Even then the meaning is temporary.  Say you are using a register to store an address, to you it is an address, while sitting there to the register it is just bits.  When you use that register with an instruction that interprets those bits as an address, then, temporarily, it is an address.  When you need to move that address to point at another item, say *p++, now that register contains an operand and result to an add operation.  8, 16, 32, or 62 bits.  Just bits that is all.

Comment: @rFactor: Registers hold bits, not data types. Registers hold 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Answer (score 2):

1) The size of registers depends (in well-defined ways) on what names you're using for them. For instance, `eax` is 32 bits wide, `ax` is 16 bits, and `ah`/`al` are 8 bits. If you're on a 64-bit system, `rax` is 64 bits wide.

The exact limits of these register sizes will depend somewhat on how you're interpreting the values (in particular, whether you're treating them as signed or unsigned). The size is what fundamentally matters, though.

2) The operating system kernel will save your process's registers while other processes, or the kernel, are running. The registers do take on other values while you're not running, but it's all transparent -- while your process is running, registers won't change out from under you.